# Is possible to use a standard .Net library in a UWP app?

Tags: .net, uwp, bitmap

I have an old .Net library that is using system.drawing.bitmap.
How I can use it in UWP project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot reference a .NET Framework library that uses `System.Drawing.Bitmap` from a UWP project.

This type is not included in either of the .NET Standard or UWP APIs surfaces.

> How I can use it in UWP project?

You can't. You will have to migrate (rewrite) your code.

Answer (score 0):

If the old .Net library you used is .NET Standard library, UWP project can reference .NET Standard library directly, if you have the .NET Standard library project, you can **right-click** the References of uwp project -> **Add Reference** -> **Choose Project Tab** and then click your .NET Standard library project to add it to your uwp app. After that, you can call the method of the library.

If you only have the dll file of .NET Standard library, you need to right-click the References of uwp project -> **Add Reference** -> **Choose Browse Tab** -> **Click Browse button** to find your dll file and add it.

If the old .Net library you used is .NET Framework library, you cannot reference the .NET Framework library from uwp, it's better to convert your .NET Framework library.